# Open a login screen from a menubar

Tags: java, swing

I wanted to create this little application for school which automatically calculates the grades you need to get in order to pass. Came up with two classes, the frame class, which basically holds the jframe and the menubar, and the login class which (obviously) handles the login form.

Now when I click on the login button from the menu, I want a new window to pop up and display the login form, which will then continue to load in the grades.
I have no idea how I can do that though, and everything I've tried failed so far.

How can I do this?

Code for class `Login`:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Login {

    public static void placeComponents(JPanel panel) {

        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Username: ");
        userLabel.setBounds(100, 10, 80, 25);
        panel.add(userLabel);

        JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
        userText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
        panel.add(userText);

        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password: ");
        passwordLabel.setBounds(10, 40, 80, 25);
        panel.add(passwordLabel);

        JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField(20);
        passwordText.setBounds(100, 40, 160, 25);
        panel.add(passwordText);

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        loginButton.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
        panel.add(loginButton);
    }

}
```

Code for my `Frame` class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    Login login = new Login();

    public Frame() {

        setTitle("Grade calculation");
        setSize(300, 300);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(editMenu);

        JMenuItem loginAction = new JMenuItem("Log in");
        JMenuItem exitAction = new JMenuItem("Close");
        JMenuItem cutAction = new JMenuItem("Cut");
        JMenuItem copyAction = new JMenuItem("Copy");
        JMenuItem pasteAction = new JMenuItem("Paste");

        JCheckBoxMenuItem checkAction = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Inloggegevens onthouden");
        fileMenu.add(loginAction);
        fileMenu.add(checkAction);
        fileMenu.add(exitAction);
        editMenu.add(cutAction);
        editMenu.add(copyAction);
        editMenu.add(pasteAction);

        loginAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            }

        });

        exitAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame me = new Frame();
        me.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        me.setResizable(false);
        me.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        me.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to put some actual code inside the `loginAction` ActionListener.  Like maybe `new Login()` or something.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a **pop-up window** in Java Swing, see some info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html). 

Here is the first example from the link above, just creating a simple message dialogue window.

```
  //default title and icon
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
        "Eggs are not supposed to be green.");
```

You can put any input fields you need in the pop-up window.

Comment: Nice! That information helped me alot, I will change some things tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that possibly can point you in the right direction with out doing too much of your project. I would not separate my GUI over multiple classes to prevent ever having your frame lose control over what's happening inside of it, a few other reasons as well. You will also probably want to create another class for your data. If you simply want to display the login details and grades in a new frame then you can easily just create another class extending JFrame for that.

Code:

```
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JMenu;
 import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
 import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;

 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 public class Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

     private JMenuItem loginAction; //defined here to allow access in actionPerformed().
     private JMenuItem exitAction;

     private JButton loginButton;

     public Frame() {

         setTitle("Grade calculation");
         setSize(300, 300);

         JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

         setJMenuBar(menuBar);

         JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
         JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
         menuBar.add(fileMenu);
         menuBar.add(editMenu);

         loginAction = new JMenuItem("Log in");
         exitAction = new JMenuItem("Close");
         JMenuItem cutAction = new JMenuItem("Cut");
         JMenuItem copyAction = new JMenuItem("Copy");
         JMenuItem pasteAction = new JMenuItem("Paste");

         JCheckBoxMenuItem checkAction = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Inloggegevens onthouden");
         fileMenu.add(loginAction);
         fileMenu.add(checkAction);
         fileMenu.add(exitAction);
         editMenu.add(cutAction);
         editMenu.add(copyAction);
         editMenu.add(pasteAction);

         loginAction.addActionListener(this);

         exitAction.addActionListener(this);
     }

     public JPanel loginPanel()
     {
         JPanel panel = new JPanel();

         panel.setLayout(null);

         JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Username: ");
         userLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
         panel.add(userLabel);

         JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
         userText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
         panel.add(userText);

         JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password: ");
         passwordLabel.setBounds(10, 40, 80, 25);
         panel.add(passwordLabel);

         JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField(20);
         passwordText.setBounds(100, 40, 160, 25);
         panel.add(passwordText);

         loginButton = new JButton("Login");
         loginButton.addActionListener(this);
         loginButton.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
         panel.add(loginButton); 

         return panel;        
     }   

     public void close()
     { 
         System.exit(0);
     }

     public void addLogin()
     {
         add(loginPanel());
         validate();
     }

     //action method
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


         if (e.getSource() == loginButton)
            System.out.println("loginButton was pressed so I should do something, maybe?");

         if (e.getSource() == loginAction)
            addLogin();

         if (e.getSource() == exitAction)
            close();
     }    

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Frame me = new Frame();
         me.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         me.setResizable(false);
         me.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         me.setVisible(true);
     }
 }
```

You will notice that I created the `loginPanel()` method to return a JPanel when called. When you select the loginAction menu item it will add the panel to the frame. It isn't as easily removed if you wanted to replace it with another panel, but I believe that you want to move away from this frame towards one for purely displaying data after.

This might not be the direction that you wish to go with your project. If not, leave a comment and I will see if I'm able to help.

Comment: If your going to following the logic, it would be better to use a CardLayout

Comment: Great recommendation. Hopefully the OP sorts his program flow and can use it.

Comment: I didn't yet start on actually creating the login panel,  but this'll be a nice start! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm, I just took the code from your login class and used it as the panel..It shows when you select login from the menu. What is your login panel supposed to display? Or are you referring to a panel when you're actually logged in?

Comment: Firstly I want the user to enter the main menu, which will be further developed from the Frame.java file. There will be a little sign saying the user has to log in using the menubar (File -> login) and then the login file will be displayed. If the users information is correct, the grades will be taken from an external file, and calculated from there.